# C# persisting data between two winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, persist

I have not been able to find a solution to my problem yet. What I have is two winforms, Main and a Configuration Settings form. The configuration settings form can be accessed from the menu of the Main form.

What I want to do is have a single instance of the Configuration settings form so when the user enters the information in the form it gets passed back to the main form and closes. But if the user decides to go back to the configuration settings form the previous entered information appears.

The configuration settings basically has two input boxes and an OK button.

How can I implement this ?

Comment: What kind of application - WinForms/WPF/WebForms?

Comment: If you think as the forms as only *showing* the data, I think you will get a clearer picture. A common mistake is to think of the forms as the first class citizens. The forms should never actually contain the data, only show it. So make some classes to represent the state of your application (e.g. a document loaded in the main form, a class with settings shown in the settings form and so on).

Comment: @sll, I've got to ask, what's the big diff between WinForms, WPF and WebForms when answering this question?

Comment: @Neowizard : it makes big difference for Web or Desctop case, for WPF or WinForms it makes difference since WPF provides much more facilities like Commands, routed events so solution could be completely different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For configuration purpose you can use singleton pattern to store configuration data.

```
class ConfigurationStorage{
      private static ConfigurationStorage _instance;

      // settng example - ConnectionString    
      public string ConnectionString {get;set;}

      public static ConfigurationStorage GetInstance(){
          return _instance ?? (_instance =  new ConfigurationStorage());
      }
}
```

In configuration form you can do:

```
ConfigurationStorage.GetInstance().ConnectionString  = "buu";
```

to store data, and same thing in Main form to retrive it (because is the same object)

Also you can  use Form Parent property to set settings explicity to MainForm.

Comment: Nicely demonstrated. The `ConfigurationStorage` is now persisted and can be accessed from anywhere within the application.

Answer (score 0):

You've got many options. For instance:

- You can store the latest serialized configuration data on the hard
  drive\DB (using some temp file).
- You can pass the last defined config as a constructor parameter (and
  return it to the calling form upon close).
- You can cancel the form's close event and hide it instead, and when
  you try to reopen it, you make it visible instead.
- you can use a singletone (like @Kamil said)

When it comes to configuration windows, I like to either store their data to the drive\DB or to pass their initial state to the constructor.